# SQL Server Error "Invalid attempt to GetBytes on column"

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

Little background:

Recently I upgraded "SQL server management studio 2005" by applying the patch from MS link
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7218

So that, I can access the recently built DB server which are in SQL Server 2008 version.

I have a server link created on the 2008 Db server which connects to a Oracle DB. earlier I didn't faced any issue but after applying the management studio patch whenever I run a query using the server link as below

```
select top 10 * from [server]..DBNAME.TABLENAME
```

OR

```
select * from [server]..DBNAME.TABLENAME
```

I get the error

> An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Invalid
>   attempt to GetBytes on column colname'. The GetBytes
>   function can only be used on columns of type Text, NText, or Image."

But if I change the query to

```
select top 10 col1,col2 from [server]..DBNAME.TABLENAME
```

OR

```
select distinct col1, col2, col3 from [server]..DBNAME.TABLENAME
```

It runs fine without any issue.

I am not sure but my believe is it's something to do with `Management Studio` ... some setting in `Management Studio` probably causing this issue.

Does anyone have any idea Or have faced this issue before. Can you please help.

EDIT: If I run the problem query using `sqlcmd` it runs fine.

Thanks.

Comment: If you think it is management studio, try running the above query via SQLCMD. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx sqlcmd -S servername -d master -Q "select * from [server]..DBNAME.TABLENAME"

Comment: @billinkc, yea I already tried that and that's why mentioned that the issue is with SSMS.

Comment: Seems like the logical answer is to stop using SELECT *?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've got that error before when using SQL 2005 management studio to a SQL 2008 server and querying a table with the DATE datetype in it.

Essentially it means that SSMS doesn't understand one of the column data types coming back to it. You said SELECT * doesn't work but SELECT col1, col2, col3 does. How many columns in the table? Try expanding the select column by column until you find the one that's confusing Management Studio . Then you can use CAST in the select clause to turn it into something Management Studio does understand.

What's probably happening here is that one of the columns is being returned from SQL 2008 as DATE, TIME, DATETIME2 or one of the other new SQL 2008 data types. While Management Studio 2005 can connect to a SQL 2008 server, it doesn't understand the new data types and cannot display them.

It's a limitation of Management Studio.

Comment: I will not downvote but this is not the problem ... same query if I run using `sqlcmd` I get no error. If it woud have been what you saying then I would have got error using sqlcmd as well ... right?

Comment: No. This is a Management Studio problem. It is not general to any form of querying (like SQLCMD). It's that Management Studio specifically does not know how to display the columns.

Answer (score 0):

as @GilaMonster stated, that's the cause of the problem.

Again, the problem is with SSMS andnot general, like if I run the query using `sqlcmd` like

```
sqlcmd -S <servername> -U login -P password -d dbname -Q "select top 10 * from [server]..DBNAME.TABLENAME"
```

it runs fine without error.

Solution:

Unistall `SSMS 2005` and install `SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio` which will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. Please try to query the sql2008 table containing the DATE field in this way (assuming that field3 is a DATE field):

```
select field1, field2, convert(datetime,field3) from tablename
```